# How to remove item from spinner when it is selected

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have 2 spinners, the 2 spinners should have different selected item.

this is the addItemsOnSpinner methode, the 2 spinners uses the same array of strings.

```
public void addItemsOnSpinner(Spinner spinner,String[] names) {

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
      }
```

How can I remove the item that I selected it in spinner 1 from spinner 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save an original of String[] names, then when selection occurs on first spinner, recreate the second spinner data adapter using the original list but removing the element you selected in spinner one, jus an idea i havanet touched android for a while